# Understanding of tangent space

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have some understanding issues with the following theorem.

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a d-dimensional smooth manifold. $p \in M$ with $(\phi, U)$ a chart around $p$. Then  $T_pM = (d\phi |_p)^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^d_0) $.

Now I wanted to try this theorem on $M = S^1=\{(x,y)^T \in \mathbb{R^2} | x^2+y^2=1\}$

So first I have to find a chart $(\phi, U) $.

My Chart is:

$\phi : S^1 \setminus \{ (1,0)^T\} \to (-\pi, \pi) \times \{0\} $

$ \phi(u,v):=(\arccos(u), 0)^T $

with $U:=(-\pi, \pi) \times \{0\} $

now $$d\phi |_p = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-p_1^2}} & 0  \\
0 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But this matrix is not invertible because the rank is 1. Can someone tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: Your $\phi$ is not even a chart, as it is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

A chart that works:
$$\phi(u,v) = u$$
in the subset $\{(u,v)\in S^1\mid u>0\}$. Yo can cover $S^1$ with three more similar charts.

Answer (score 0):

The image of $\phi$ is rather unusual.  $\phi(U)$ should be an *open* set in a copy of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ is the dimension of your manifold.  $(-\pi,\pi)\times\{0\}$ is *not* an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Instead, $\phi$ should map to $\mathbb{R}$ (forgetting about the $\times\{0\}$) and then the differential of $\phi$ should make more sense.

Also, as written, you are writing $d\phi|_p$ as a map from the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is one-dimensional) instead of the tangent space of $S^1$, which is a one-dimensional subspace of the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: but if I chose some open set instead of $\{0\}$ then I it won't be a chart.